# Creating a vector in a function in r

Tags: r, function, vector

Basically I'm trying to create a weight vector to use for weighted cumulative averages.

I have tried to write a function that gives a vector with the first element = 1.5,
second and third element = 1, fourth to sixth = 0.75 etc.

```
w<- function(n){
  weights<-rep(0,n)
  weights[1]<- 1.5
  for (i in 2:3){
    weights[i]<- 1
  }
  for(i in 4:6){
    weights[i]<- 0.75
  }
  for (i in 7:10){
    weights[i]<- 0.5
  }
  for (i in 11:n){
    weights[i]<- 0.1
  }
}
```

No errors come up when I run the function or give a value for n, but no weight vector is created either.

If I just run the code in the function replacing n with say 10 I get what I want.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You need to return `weights`, either implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Your function does not have a return value. Try putting `return(weights)` at the end of the function body.

Comment: You could just do `w <- function(n) rep(c(1.5, 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.1), c(1:4, n))`

Comment: Thanks, putting a return did the trick.